# Adding the complex('a+bj') or float('') no matter from input or manually setted losts some accuracy. Just wonder why and how to solve it

Tags: python

I am just getting to learn python as my first language.

In python when I transfer the string type of input() to complex('a+b j') in order to try the addition, the answer of the addition is somehow weird.

I have tried addition of float(), the answer is exactly fit.
But why complex weird. how can i fix that.

[image: complex is weird but float is exactly fit.]

I have tried this

```
aComplex = complex("10.11+2j")
bComplex = complex("10.2356+5j")
print(aComplex + bComplex)

aFloat = 10.11
bFloat = 10.2356
print(aFloat + bFloat)

aStrInput = input('a= ')
bStrInput = input('b= ')
aFloatInput = float(aStrInput)
bFloatInput = float(bStrInput)
print(aFloatInput + bFloatInput)
```

and get

```
(20.345599999999997+7j)
20.345599999999997
a= 10.11
b= 10.2356
20.345599999999997
```

thanks.~ so maybe the question can solve my problem [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
i will check it later.() thanks.

Comment: If you have a problem with complex numbers, post a script as text that focuses just on that issue. We want something we can easily run, not a screenshot of some tool you are using. Don't prompt for input unless that is part of the problem. `aNumInput = complex("10.11+2j")` is better for test.

Comment: Wooo, so cool. but addition of float() is okay, while complex is weird. Is that normal?

Comment: What do you mean by "weird"? Are you saying that you've lost some accuracy? What is the result you expect?

Comment: Adding like floats is: `10.11+10.2356` is `20.345599999999997` ... is that the weirdness?